# Bash for loop print two parameters

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash and want to write a simple program which takes an even amount of parameters. The script should always take two parameters and print them in one line as first an last name. A usage of the script could be:

```
getnames John Doe Max Muster Tim Stone
```

The output should be:

```
1. Person: John Doe
2. Person: Max Muster
3. Person: Tim Stone
```

The output I get right now:

```
::> getnames John Doe Max Muster Tim Stone
/home/user/bin/getnames: line 17: x: command not found
1. Person: John 
/home/user/bin/getnames: line 17: x: command not found
2. Person: Doe 
/home/user/bin/getnames: line 17: x: command not found
3. Person: Max 
/home/user/bin/getnames: line 17: x: command not found
4. Person: Muster 
/home/user/bin/getnames: line 17: x: command not found
5. Person: Tim 
/home/user/bin/getnames: line 17: x: command not found
6. Person: Stone
```

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No names given"
        exit 1
elif [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
        echo "Please enter at least one first and one last name"
        exit 1
elif [ $(($#%2)) -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Please always enter a first name and a last name for one person"
        exit 1
fi

count=1

for x in $*; do
        echo "$count. Person: $x $(x + 1)"
        let "x+=2"
        let count++
done
```

Comment: That looks good. What's the problem?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The only problem is the $(x + 1) which doesn't work so far.

Comment: You should probably mention that in the question and either post the error you are getting or compare the expected and the actual outputs.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added the output I get right now to the post.

Comment: Thanks. The answer here should fix you right up. The only alternative I can think of is using `eval` to add a level of indirection to `x` but that is just not a good way to do it. It's also much more limited than `shift`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **shift** command.

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No names given"
        exit 1
elif [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
        echo "Please enter at least one first and one last name"
        exit 1
elif [ $(($#%2)) -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Please always enter a first name and a last name for one person"
        exit 1
fi

count=1

while (( "$#" )); do
        echo "$((count++)). Person: $1 $2"
        shift 2
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to do this in a for loop?

Comment: @TomStroub. Why does it have to be a `for` loop specifically?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Idk I'm just writing this for myself to get better in bash. This must be possible in a for loop or not? :/

Comment: @TomStrob. Oh it's possible, but I would argue that it wouldn't make you better at Bash. Sure you'd know of an arcane technique, but this answer is the simple way to do it.

Comment: @TomStrob. I couldn't resist posting another answer, but please mark this as the accepted one.

Comment: You could write `echo "$((count++))...` and remove the `let` line. +1 though

Answer (score 3):

Yet more ways:

1. this doesn't *quite* give your desired output but is short and clear.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   printf "Person: %s %s\n" "$@" | nl -s ". "
   ```
2. with a for-loop and using [variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

   ```
   for ((i=2; i<=$#; i+=2)); do 
       j=$((i-1))
       printf "%d. Person %s %s\n" $((i/2)) "${!j}" "${!i}"
   done
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is using [`shift`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html), as shown in [tso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49841140/2988730). If you absolutely insist on doing it the hard way (using a `for` loop), you have a couple of alternatives **neither of which I would recommend**.

1. Use [`printf`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) command instead of `echo` to do your output. When  `count%2` is zero, print `count/2`, `$x` as the first name, and no newline. When `count%2` is 1, print `$x` as the last name, and a newline. That's if `count` starts from zero.

   You probably want to loop over `"$@"` rather than `$*` even with your current setup. Some folks might have legitimate spaces in their name, like `"Billy Bob" Thornton`.
2. You can run your loop over the numbers from 1 to `$#`, and  use [indirect variable referencing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html). IVR is using a variable to name another variable.

   The old and portable way to do indirection would be something like `eval FIRST="\$$x"` or `FIRST="$(eval \$$x)"`. As of version 2.0, bash allows you to do `FIRST="${!x}"`. This new form is [not a standard notation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41418/79307) between shells.

Answer (score 0):

With a for loop

```
for x ; do
    let count++
    if [ $((count%2)) -eq 1 ] ; then
            name="$x"
    else
            echo "$((count/2)). Person: $name $x"
    fi
done
```